# Change visibility of TextView for selected item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a PlayList where I set the currently playing song to selected, checked and give focus to it for the background selector as well as showing the current song on top of the list.

Now I also want to show a hidden TextView when this item is selected but somehow I fail.
I bet it's easy but maybe it's not my day today ;-)

```
public static void changeUI() {
    position = PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER;

    mediaListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mediaListView.setSelection(position);

    mediaListView.getChildAt(position).setVisibility(nowPlaying.VISIBLE);

    View v = mediaListView.getChildAt(position);
    if (v != null) {
        v.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

I try to get the selected child and set the TextView "nowPlaying" to VISIBLE but nothing happens.

*** UPDATE, post complete code as requested ***

```
public class PlayList{

CustomAdapter customAdapter = null;
static TextView playingSong, nowPlaying;
static ListView mediaListView;
public static String getMode;
static Context context;
private static int position;
private static boolean playlistVisible;

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_SORTING_ITEM = "selected_sorting_item";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player_activity_playlist);
    context = PlayList.this;

    init();
}

private void init() {
    getViews();
    setListeners();

    if (PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.size() <= 0) {
        PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST = UtilFunctions
                .listOfSongs(getApplicationContext());
    }
    setListItems();
}

private void setListItems() {
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.player_activity_playlist_listitem_song,
            PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST);
    mediaListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    mediaListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
}

private void getViews() {
    mediaListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMusic);
    nowPlaying = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nowPlaying);
}

private void setListeners() {
    mediaListView
    .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("TAG", "TAG Tapped INOUT(IN)");
            PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED = false;
            PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER = position;
            boolean isServiceRunning = UtilFunctions
                    .isServiceRunning(SongService.class.getName(),
                            getApplicationContext());
            if (!isServiceRunning) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SongService.class);
                startService(i);
            } else {
                PlayerConstants.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER
                .sendMessage(PlayerConstants.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER
                        .obtainMessage());
            }

            // Return to calling activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AudioPlayer.class);
            setResult(100, in);
            // Closing PlayListView
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public static void changeUI() {
    position = PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER;

    mediaListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mediaListView.setSelection(position);

    mediaListView.getChildAt(position).setVisibility(nowPlaying.VISIBLE);

    View v = mediaListView.getChildAt(position);
    if (v != null) {
        v.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: You are not calling changeUI(), you have to call it in the onItemClick().
And when you get the object using mediaListView.getChildAt(position), you are probably getting a `TextView` that is already visible, because this `TextView` is the description of the `listview`

Comment: @Lennon I'm calling changeUI() in onResume, sorry, didn't copy it. Well, this is so stupid, Im doing this so often to hide and show views...  simply don't get it done. 'nowPlaying' is returned null.

Comment: Try to call changeUI() into  onItemClick() of mediaListView

Comment: @Lennon Doing so causes an NPE at `mediaListView.getChildAt(position).setVisibility(nowPlaying.VISIBLE);`

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this: 
 1. setOnItemClickListener for listview
 1. Pass position value in adapter by object of adapter (you can create a method in adapter class)
 2. Call notifyDatasetchange();
 3. in getView create an if else

```
if(selectedPosition == position(getview position) )
 textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I hope It will help

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick. I had to do it in the adapter.